# Neglect variable from Query in entity framework where condition C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
public ActionResult sortFilteredItem(string sortByValue,string brand,string category,int price=0 )
{
  var sortedData = (dynamic)null;
  if (sortByValue != "")
  {
    if(sortByValue == "ltoh")
    {
      sortedData = DB.Prouducts.where(x=> x.brandName == brand & x.catName == category & x.price == price).ToList();
    }

  }
 return View(sortedData);
}
```

how i can neglect if `price=0` from query means that it does not make any impact on EF query because if `price=0` the query does not returning expected output.Because i have not any record that has 0 `price` so the query  is always returning `null`.

```
if(price != 0)
{
    sortedData = DB.Prouducts.where(x=> x.brandName == brand & x.catName == category & x.price == price).ToList();
}
else
{
    sortedData = DB.Prouducts.where(x=> x.brandName == brand & x.catName == category).ToList();
}
```

i have tried like this it is working good but that is lengthy process.if i have 4 or 5 more variable that,s optional so it is necessary to check null value first for working.Any recommendation ?

Comment: you don't use and operator correctly IMHO. You should use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: that,s not problem i always use single `&` operator so that,s not an issue. issue is only to check null and neglect from query as i asked above.

Comment: there is already an answer that will solve your problem AFAIK. But using bitwise operator when you don't mean to compare like that is a bad practice. I did not answer your question. That is why I am putting it here in the comments section. Happy coding

Comment: you are right i does not said that you are wrong i just tell to you that is not problem. so you give me suggestion to use `&&` that.s great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is apply filters only if the condition holds. Let's say you need to check catName and price. So:

```
var query = DB.Prouducts.Where(x=> x.brandName == brand);
if (category != null)
{
     query = query.Where(x => x.catName == category);
}

if (price != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.price == price)
}

sortedData = query.ToList();
```

Obviously you'll need one "if" per filter, but it is much better than considering all possible combinations.

Comment: so that is lengthy process if i have to check 4 to 5 variables null.so i have to check like this `if(brandName != "" & catName != "" & price != ""){ some code}`and so on it will make 5 to 6 condtions that,s is real proble.

Comment: @Shakir, perhaps i didn't explain the answer well enough. see update

Answer (score 4):

You can use the fllowing logic;

```cs
sortedData = DB.Prouducts.where(x=> x.brandName == brand 
    && x.catName == category 
    && (price == 0 || x.price == price)) //use this approach for every optional param
    .ToList();
```

Comment: same problem again if `price=0` the query always return `null` because i have no any record in DB that has 0 price.

Comment: @Shakir, this condition does not do that. it is doing like, if  input `price==0` then `(price == 0 || x.price == price)` returns true. So if the code above does not work, you should look somewhere elste to solve your problem